# passing a variable to classes

Tags: java, android, variables

i can not figure out how to pass the results from onActivityResult to resultBreakdown. I know there is a get/set and I've looked at a few tutorials, but I'm just not getting it. Or, Is there a better way? The program runs fine up if i comment out */ the resultBreakdown Class

Side note, I just started with java/android. I'm a better learner at doing then reading. I know my code is a little clumsy. Thanks for the help

Note: i edited code to reflect suggested changes

```
package com.example.spdwiz18.testproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class GrindLogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView barcodeResult;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gringlogactivity);

    // this is how to set id's from the xml file with vNames. (julianDate)
    TextView bcc = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.bccheck);
    TextView pc = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.pcode);
    TextView pd = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.pdate);
    // TextView en = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.estnum);
    TextView sn = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.seqnum);
    TextView nw = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.nweight);
    barcodeResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_result);
    TextView julianDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datecode);
    TextView td1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todaydate1);


    // this is how you get a julian/original date for android
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        int julian = now.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    // this how to set you current date for android
        Date date = new Date();
        String stringDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
    // this is how to set your vNames to your method variables
        julianDate.setText(Integer.toString(julian));
        td1.setText(stringDate);

}

/*add click event to the scan barcode button */
public void scanBarcode(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanBarcodeActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (requestCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            if (data != null) {
                Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
                barcodeResult.setText("Barcode value : " + barcode.displayValue);
            } else {
                barcodeResult.setText("No Barcode Found");
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
public void resultsBreakdown(String result) {
if (result.length() == 44) {
    pc.setText(result.CharSequence(2,10));
    pd.setText(result.CharSequence(13,18));
    sn.setText(result.CharSequence(21,27));
    nw.setText(result.CharSequence(13,18));
} else {
    bcc.setText("invalid barcode");
}
```

}

Comment: Did not quite get your question . `resultsBreakdown` is a method not a class in your code . can you pls explain your problem

Comment: I think there should be `resultCode ` instead of `requestCode` in `requestCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted needs a lot of work - so this answer most likely is just partial

(1) TextView initialization in wrong place

The `TextView`s declared as class instance variables cannot also be initialized at that point.  So leave the declarations there (where bardcodeResult is declared):

```
TextView barcodeResult;
TextView bcc;
TextView pc;
TextView pd;
TextView sn;
TextView nw;
```

but move the initialization to the `onCreate` method in the same manner `barcodeResult`.

```
// in onCreate
barcodeResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_result);
bcc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bccheck);
pc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pcode);
pd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pdate);
sn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seqnum);
nw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nweight);
```

(2) The syntax is of `resultsBreakdown` is invalid and the functionality is wrong (need to invoke `setText`)- try:

```
  public void resultsBreakdown(String result) {
    if (result.length() == 44) {
         pc.setText(result.CharSequence(2,10));
         pd.setText(result.CharSequence(13,18));
       sn.setText(result.CharSequence(21,27));
         nw.setText(result.CharSequence(13,18));
    } else {
        bcc.setText("invalid barcode");
    }
}
```

(3) Actually invoke the `resultsBreakdown` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (requestCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            if (data != null) {
                Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
                barcodeResult.setText("Barcode value : " +                  barcode.displayValue);

                //-- THIS LINE WAS ADDED TO CALL METHOD
                resultsBreakdown(barcode.displayValue.toString());
           } else {
               barcodeResult.setText("No Barcode Found");
           }
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: (1) moved it, didn't realize i had it in the wrong spot. my personal comments to my self should have told me that..

Comment: i edited code based on you suggestion, please bare with me as i have no formal education on this. learning on my own. i see how you edited the resultsBreakdown, but i don't quiet understand. also could you explain invoking? and i still don't see how the barcode results from the barcode scan get passed to this new method (im probly not asking the right question.

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be `resultCode` instead of `requestCode` in `requestCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS`

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
                barcodeResult.setText("Barcode value : " + barcode.displayValue);
                resultsBreakdown(barcode.displayValue)
            } else {
                barcodeResult.setText("No Barcode Found");
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
public void resultsBreakdown(String barcodeData){
    if (barcodeData.length == (44)) {
        pc = (barcodeData.CharSequence(2,10);
        pd = (barcodeData.CharSequence(13,18);
        sn = (barcodeData.CharSequence(21,27);
        nw = (barcodeData.CharSequence(13,18);
    )else(
        bcc = "invalid barcode";
    }
)               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

resultBreakdown neither a class nor a method.İt isn't even compile. You change your resultBreakDown to Method:

```
public void resultsBreakdown(Barcode barcodeResult){
    if (barcodeResult.length == (44)) {
        pc = (barcodeResult.CharSequence(2,10);
        pd = (barcodeResult.CharSequence(13,18);
        sn = (barcodeResult.CharSequence(21,27);
        nw = (barcodeResult.CharSequence(13,18);
}       else{
                bcc = "invalid barcode";
    }
```

and later in  onActivityResult call your method with Barcode parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> The code is incomplete as you have not placed `ScanBarcodeActivity` java file. Well... I am placing a small code in my project which will clear your concept and even you can use it.

---

Here suppose i am in Activity `MyClassA.java` where is a button and when it is clicked it will start another activity `MyClassB.java`, Remember it will start that activity along with layout.. from that activity you have to finish it on certain event and when it is finished your `MyClassA.java` will collect its result...

---

From Activity `MyClassA.java` on button click i want to start a activity 
 `MyClassB.java` for result:

```
ContactsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ContactsBtn.setEnabled(false);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyClassA.this, MyClassB.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });
```

Where `REQUEST_CODE` should be declared in `MyClassA` class as public `static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;`

---

Now From Activity `MyClassB.java` on particular event say on click of a button you want to close this activity and want to send result to previous activity :

```
SelectContactsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("WhitelistNames", (ArrayList<String>) WhitelistNames);

            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
          }
    });
```

Here i am placing `WhitelistNames` array list as result to be sent to calling activity.

---

Now From Activity `MyClassA.java` again you have to collect the result with :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
    {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            ArrayList<String> WhitelistNames = data.getStringArrayListExtra("WhitelistNames");

            Log.d("ContactsContracts", "\nPREVIOUS LIST  : "+ContactsNumbers);
        }
   }
}
```

Remember `onActivityResult` method should be part of your `MyClassA.java` class and should not be in `onCreate` nor in some other existing standard methods of this class.

> Hope it helps

Comment: i did have a ScanBarcodeActivity java file. as stated everything works up till the point that i want to pass the results from the scan to a new method ( think i said that right}  still learning/self teaching.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyones help. This one worked as needed

```
package com.example.spdwiz18.testproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class GrindLogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView barcodeResult;
TextView bcc;
TextView pc;
TextView pd;
TextView sn;
TextView nw;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gringlogactivity);


    bcc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bccheck);
    pc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pcode);
    pd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pDate);
    // TextView en = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.estnum);
    sn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seqnum);
    nw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nweight);
    barcodeResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_result);
    TextView julianDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datecode);
    TextView td1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todaydate1);

    // this is how to set id's from the xml file with vNames. (julianDate)

    // this is how you get a julian/original date for android
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        int julian = now.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    // this how to set you current date for android
        Date date = new Date();
        String stringDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
    // this is how to set your vNames to your method variables
        julianDate.setText(Integer.toString(julian));
        td1.setText(stringDate);

}

/*add click event to the scan barcode button */
public void scanBarcode(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanBarcodeActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (requestCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            if (data != null) {
                Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
                barcodeResult.setText("Barcode value : " + barcode.displayValue);
                resultsBreakdown(barcode.displayValue.toString());
            } else {
                barcodeResult.setText("No Barcode Found");
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
public void resultsBreakdown(CharSequence result) {
    if (result.length() == 44) {
        pc.setText(result.subSequence(2,10));
        pd.setText(result.subSequence(13,18));
        sn.setText(result.subSequence(21,27));
        nw.setText(result.subSequence(13,18));
    } else {
        bcc.setText("invalid barcode");
    }
```

}}